# Excel VBA - For Loop Need To Skip First Element In Web Scrape

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new/inexperienced at VBA and I'm (seemingly) one small step from finishing a project that been kicking my butt. For some background, I'm scraping a website and navigating to the appropriate "tbody" tag and iterating through the encompassed "tr" tags. In each tr I am expecting two "td" cells. The problem is the first tr has a "th" tag with a colspan of 2, meaning obviously there is only one child in that tr and the code crashes out. What I don't (yet) know how to do is to skips or account for the exception in the first tr. Here is the relevant snippet of the code:

```
R = 1

For Each ele In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(13).getElementsByTagName("td")


WSW.Range("H" & R).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
WSW.Range("I" & R).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent

R = R + 1

Next
```

Not sure if I've walked myself down a rabbit hole, if the code is salvageable, or if the slate for this section of the code should be recreated. Thank you for any help.

Comment: `if not ele = "th" then ........... End if R = R + 1 Next`  Just throwing that out there.

Comment: OK, just tried that, am I missing extra components to that because it's still erroring out. Thank you.

Comment: I really don't know.  What is the error?  Why don't you catch the error and let us know what it is?

Comment: Run-time error '424': Object required. This occurs on the WSW.Range("I" & R).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent line since there is a th that has a colspan of 2. The if statement isn't triggering it seems.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the html?

Comment: Can you share the html using the snippet tool via [edit] ? And are you after everything in the table including headers? There has to be a better way to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index of getElementsByTagName is zero to *n* based but the count (aka .length) is one to *n* based. You use R as the index reference so it does double duty.

```
dim R as long
R = 1

For R=1 to  IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(13).getElementsByTagName("td").length -1

    with IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(13).getElementsByTagName("td")(R)
        WSW.Range("H" & R).Value = .Children(0).textContent
        WSW.Range("I" & R).Value = .Children(1).textContent
    end with

Next R
```

Comment: Excellent, this is it. I had to make one small tweak which was the "td"s in your solution should be "tr"s since it goes tbody->tr->td and it's the children of the tr's I'm after. Simple fix though and much appreciated. I'll mark your answer as the solution.